# Complex table design based on diagram selection

Tags: web-app, tables, layout, data-tables, page-layout

enter image description hereI am building a web based tool to manage car repairs. The user would select an area of the car and a part from a list of supplied parts. They would then select what they wish to do with this part. The generated table becomes very long in width to use and the layout involves scrolling up and down the screen to be able to add more parts

Any help would be really appreciated. I have created a couple compacted versions but would love some new ideas/suggestions.

**Current setup**

[image: current version]

**Alternate idea**

[image: Other idea]